# Windows Phone 7 Dev Tools: cannot see menu for device emulator

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have installed the dev tools. I have both visual studio 2010 and Visual Studio C# Express. After install it launched VStudio, I create a windows phone app, when running it says "Error   1   Zune software is not installed. Install the latest version of Zune software."

I saw on the internet that I had to connect to emulator in tools menu except I don't have such menu. So is there something I missed ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to deploy to a device. In Visual Studio, next to the debug button (green arrow), there's a drop down box. Set that to `Windows Phone 7 Emulator` and then try running the app. This should launch the emulator instead of trying to deploy to an actual device.

Comment: "Set that to Windows Phone 7 Emulator" that's what I'd like to do but the menu seems missing that's what I said :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant literally in the 'Tools' menu :). When you installed the dev tools, it should've installed VS 2010 for Windows Phone. This is different from VS 2010 and VS C# Express.

Comment: Finally it was on toolbar so it's ok :)